# How to get a cookie with server side js

Tags: javascript, cookies

I would like to access a cookie using client side javascript. I created it using the "client-sessions" module for Node.js and I made sure to set httpOnly to false. This is not my session cookie, it only holds a color theme. How would I access the cookie?

*Edit: I don't know if it matters, but this is **not** an AJAX request*

Comment: You mean [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/)?

Comment: Yes. I will change that

Comment: Please clarify the difference between: _**How to get a cookie with server side js**_ and this: _**I would like to access a cookie using client side javascript**_

Comment: I would like to get the information stored in the cookie, or, in other words, access the cookie